# Trying to get through gulpfile fro bash terminal .bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Tags: bash

I have just started with a tutorial.After installing gulp when i run the following command from bash terminal to create gulpfile

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
gulp.task('default', function() {
});
```

but i get error
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `(' . I know i am missing something very basic but i have tried a lot of solutions and answers on stake over flow as well as other forums without any result. It might help to mention that while installing gulp i got warning npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"}) but i read about it over here that it is best to ignore this error as it mainly pertains to OS

Comment: You need to run gulp first, you can't give gulp commands to bash.

Comment: Gulp is a NodeJS tool. You don't run it with bash, you run it with NodeJS. I suggest you find yourself a better tutorial :)

Comment: If you need to create a file, start your text editor and create it there.

Comment: The code fragment is not something that should be interpreted by bash.